# Use AWK to get unique count of record file based on certain columns

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have an AWK command to modify to get a unique count of a record file based on primary keys. Inside record file, there 21 elements, column 1 and 18 being the PKs. The record is all on one row, the record seperator is \^ and field seperator is |. This is what I have so far but it still is giving me the total # of records in the file but not unique:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\\^";FS="\\|";} {a[ $1  $18 ]++;}END{print length(a);}' filename
```

**Sample Data:**

```
1|01212121|0|OUTGOING| | | | | |57 OHARE DR|not available|DALLAS|TX|03560|US|1131142334825|1|Jan 15 2004 11:12:06:576AM|Jan 15 2004  2:54:41:226PM|SYSTEM|\^
```

There are 2 millions rows of this sort of data and I have 30 duplicates.

Expected output should : 1999970

Comment: Provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: You said the PK is column 1 and 18, but you're using column 1 and 19 in the script.

Comment: Sorry, just updated it.

Comment: wait are you incrementing the index given a key created from $1 $18 ? just do = 1 rather than ++ ? or do i not understand the syntax

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `python` and `sed`?

Comment: I've tried =1 as well. Got the same result. I'm fairly new to using AWK and scripting, so can someone what exactly the a [$1 $18] is doing?

Comment: Then if you're new why do you have to resort to awk? Just curious.

Comment: it is a requirement

Comment: DMZ crap. Note that RS can only hold one character, like FS. Is it assured that `\^` will always be followed by a newline?

Comment: no, the entire data set is sitting on one row. As in if I do a wc -l on the file, it will return 1.

Comment: So we're talking about a ~2'000'000*100 char line input, to get it right?

Comment: 2 million records of the sample data ive included on one row

Answer (score 1):

Use GNU awk for multi-char RS and use SUBSEP between your array index component fields to make the result unique:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\\^"; FS="|"} NF>1{a[$1,$18]} END{print length(a)}' filename
```

You need the `NF>1` test if your input file/line ends with `\^\n` instead of just `\n`. We know it does end with `\n` because you said `if I do a wc -l on the file, it will return 1` and `wc -l` only counts `\n`s and your 1 sample input line ends in `\^` so that all leads me to believe that your file does end with `\^\n` and so the test for `NF>1` is necessary to avoid including the blank record after the final `\^`.

Answer (score 0):

At least the record separator RS can only hold a single character. Since everthing is congested in a single line you need to choose the last character of your data rows as RS and discard the last field (consisting of `\`).
Fix it like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="^";FS="|"} {a[$1,$18]++} END{print length(a)}' filename
```

Note that awk will now split on every `^` it encounters in the input. Should you require to split only on `\^` it'd suggest the following:

```
sed 's/\\^/\n/g' filename |awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"} {a[$1,$18]++} END{print length(a)}'
```

**Edit:**
Incorporated remarks from @Ed.

Comment: wrt `The record separator RS and the field separator FS can only hold a single character.` - the FS contains a multi-character regexp string in any awk and in GNU awk the RS can also be such a regexp string (POSIX requires 1 char RS and multi-char is undefined). Never try to create a unique index by concatenating strings, use `,` between them (or FS or SUBSEP). The problem is that `a bc` and `ab c` are both `abc` when concatenated so you need something between them to create a unique value for each combination.

Comment: Added that, so that the suggestion looks ok. @EdMorton

Comment: @EdMorton I'm unsure about sed being able to parse such a huge line, any comment on that?

Comment: I expect sed will choke on it, the OP should just use GNU awk for multi-char RS.